# What Commands to use, when using grep, when One Would Want To Search for a Text Inside A Folder with several PHP Files?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to search for a text string inside a php files. But for me to make the search, I will have to open the .php files one after another.

I am not a programmer, but I am learning by my own. I am editing an OpenCart Theme. I don't have PHP coding skills yet.

How to command grep (linux command line) to search for a text string, that will do the search for me and search all the PHP files contained in a folder and sub-folders?

I'm looking for the OpenCart PHP file that contains the following strings:

> "catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js", "catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"

I am currently using Linux Mint, alsong side with windows xp.

Comment: Are you on windows, osx, linux?

Comment: `ack` or `ag`, or maybe `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "my string"`.

Comment: or `grep -irl "search string" *`

Comment: @dave I used them both. Linux Mint and XP. If you may... please mention a tool for each of them.

Comment: Thank you guys for the inputs, I've tried and tested almost all of your suggestion. Options I did not use, were Dreamweaver, Aptana and Eclipse.

Comment: Guys, for the very specific purpose of searching the text string from several files. I've tested and proved that dave's option is the champion. It's the fastest and efficient way to do the job.  @dave thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using linux mint, open up the root folder you want to search in, and grep for the string you want to find in files:
i.e., if your project is in /var/www/yoursite, then open up a terminal, and type:

```
cd /var/www/yoursite
grep -irl "catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js" *
```

This will show you a list of every file that string occurs in, recursively inside of the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option for Windows:
[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html)'s "Find in Files" feature.

And there are other programs (IDEs) that run on Windows, Mac, and Linux with similar features, including:

- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)
- [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

Unlike UltraEdit, which has a free trial but is a commercial program, the other programs listed above are free and are also have more full-fledged support for PHP (make sure you download the right version of them or install the respective PHP plugin they offer if you want those features).

Otherwise, if you don't want to install any new software, @dave's answer will work on Linux and Mac, and could work on Windows too if you have a tool like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dreamweaver (commercial) or programmer's notepad (free). Both support search in files.

Answer (score 0):

[ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com/)'s pretty nice:

```
ack -Q catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js
```

You can also use a regular expression if you'd like:

```
ack 'catalog/view/javascript/jquery/[^.]+\.js'
```

By default, ack will search all files that make sense to search (e.g., text files, source files…). If you want to limit it further to only PHP files, tack `--php` on the end as well.